# Forwarding a request from Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, express, asp.net-web-api

I need to forward / redirect request received by nodejs endpoint to a .net 7 web API end point. Nodejs endpoint is triggered by an external party and it receives the request as expected. the problem is redirecting / forwarding from nodejs to .NET web api endpoint, its not getting triggered.

This is my code block.

```
exports.rerouteIncomingEmail = async (req, res)  => {

    var to = extractRequestHeaders(req.headers, 'x-recipient');
    var endPoint = await services.getPushEndpointFromEmailList(to,req.app.locals.db);

    endPoint ? res.redirect(308,endPoint) : res.send(200,'endpoint not found');    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using res.redirect, you have to proxy the request to the.NET API endpoint. Make a new request from your Node.js server to the .NET API endpoint, and then send the response from that request back to the original caller. This can be done using libraries like axios.

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.rerouteIncomingEmail = async (req, res) => {
    var to = extractRequestHeaders(req.headers, 'x-recipient');
    var endPoint = await services.getPushEndpointFromEmailList(to,req.app.locals.db);
  
    if (!endPoint) {
        res.status(200).send('endpoint not found');
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Proxy the request to the .NET API
        const apiResponse = await axios({
            method: req.method, // Keep the same method
            url: endPoint,
            headers: req.headers, // Keep the same headers
            data: req.body, // Keep the same body
        });
    
        // Send back the response from the .NET API to the original caller
        res.status(apiResponse.status).json(apiResponse.data);
    } catch (error) {
        // Error handling: Send a 500 status code and the error message
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
};
```